# Issue resizing image in xournal

Tags: pdf, images

I am trying to add a signature image to a pdf using xournal, which has worked many times for me in the past. This time, however, I am able to insert the image, but then it will not resize or move when I click and drag on the image, its edges, or its corners using either the left or right mouse buttons.

Is there a way to diagnose or solve this problem?

So far, I have tried rebooting, updating everything, and looking for the (nonexistent?) documentation. When I open xournal from the command line, it does give

> Gtk-Message: 05:56:40.011: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

although this seems irrelevant.

If there is a better forum to post this question in, I am happy to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same symptoms today. Disabling XInput (in the Tools menu) restored the resizing and moving functionality.